Command "confluent local kafka start" is not working without internet connectivity
Command "confluent local kafka start" is not working without internet connectivity.
I have loaded the docker image in the local docker registry already.
I am behind a firewall, I can't connect to docker.io.
If I can get the image it is trying to load, then I can load it manually.
I have already turned off the following
confluent configuration update disable_update_check true
confluent configuration update disable_feature_flags true

Don't know whether it is relevant here.
Could someone tell me what I am missing here? Is internet connectivity really required ?
REPOSITORY                     TAG             IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
confluentinc/confluent-local   7.6.0           94f3abe4bf28   8 weeks ago    678MB

When I run the following command, it is not starting the kafka broker.
 $ confluent local kafka start
The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment only, NOT for production usage. See more: https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Error: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:50753->[::1]:53: read: connection refused

Suggestions:
    This command has been verified to work with Docker v4.25.0. Verify that you are not using a newer, unverified version of Docker.

I tried the same thing in my local laptop after turning off the Wifi, I could replicate the same error. Once I connected wifi back, the command worked just fine.
